# how to combine R ifelse() and kable()

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I have R Markdown scripts I run periodically which contain conditional tables with what I'll call violators. Here's an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c("Jack", "Jill"), Violator = c("F", "F"))

#>   Person Violator
#> 1   Jack        F
#> 2   Jill        F
```

I only want to show violators (Violator == "T") and there aren't any this month. So my 'normal' kable code below gives me this error, *"subscript out of bounds"* which I'd expect.

How can I modify my kable code to 'do nothing' if violator does not equal "T". Is `ifelse()` the way to go? I'm open to `kableExtra()` solutions.

```
kable(df %>% filter(Violator == "T"), "html", align = "l") %>%
  kable_styling("striped", "hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T, background = "#FFFFFF") %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1)
```

Comment: Try to filter your dataframe before passing it to `kable`. E.g., `df %>% filter(Violator == "T") %>% kable("html", align = "l") %>% etc.`

Comment: @Andrew Just tried that but I get the same error _"subscript out of bounds"_. I don't think `kable()` can print a table of size 0, unless I misunderstood you. `df %>% filter(Violator == "T")` is going to return a table with 0 rows.

Comment: do `df1 <- df %>% filter(Violator == "T")` then check condition `if (nrow(df1) > 0)` and apply `kable` on `df1`.

Comment: Apologies--misread your question!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple approach should work, I think:

````
```{r}
temp <- df %>% filter(Violator == "T")

if(nrow(temp) != 0){
kable(temp, "html", align = "l") %>%
  kable_styling("striped", "hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T, background = "#FFFFFF") %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1)
}
```
````

Comment: Instead of creating an additional object you can use `any(df$Violator == TRUE)`

Comment: #PoGibas:  From the question, `df$Violator` contains string values `"T"` or `"F"`.  Your test `any(df$Violator == TRUE)` will always return `FALSE`, because `TRUE` will be converted to the string value `"TRUE"` for the comparison.